# from legacy state to useReducer nested elements React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, use-reducer

i have this legacy code where we have height as an object with heightUnits nested inside it,

before we were changing the height like so

```
 this.setState(prevState => ({
    height: {
    ...prevheight,
    [heightUnit]: heightValue
    }
   }));
```

and i turned the above code into a dispatch like so

```
const onChangeHeight = useCallback((heightValue, heightUnit) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'height-change', [heightUnit]: heightValue });
    clearErrors();
  }, [clearErrors]);
```

```
    case 'height-change': return { ...state, height: { ...state.height, heightUnit: action.heightUnit }};
```

but the value is being returned as undefined did I translate the code from class components to functional components correctly?

Comment: It doesn't look like `action.heightUnit` is defined, so when you try to set state with it, there's nothing there.  This: `[heightUnit]` uses this the stored value of `heightUnit` as the key in the `action` object.  `action` _has no_ key named `heightUnit`.

Comment: thank you @MattMorgan you did open my eyes to check that and you are right, apparently, the legacy code meant that [heightUnit] is treated as a key rather than data so it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const onChangeHeight = useCallback((heightValue, heightUnit) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'height-change', heightUnit, heightValue });
    clearErrors();
  }, [clearErrors]);
```

```
case 'height-change': return { ...state, height: { ...state.height, [action.heightUnit]: action.heightValue }};
```

the brackets indicate that heightUnit is a key inside the height object getting the valye from the onChangeHeight Function